# iOS Bluetooth caching error?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am extremely confused on this matter and wonder if anyone has any ideas as I am not sure what the problem is and my best guess is caching. When I run this application about 95% of the time it will connect correctly and access the alert characteristic but will not trigger didUpdateValueFor. Sometimes though when I change, or re-install the app it works correctly and does trigger. I know the peripheral value is updating correctly as I tested in on other apps. I'm working with a iPhone 6 and I've restarted multiple times. I am unsure what does cause it to work sometimes and thus have not been able to debug. Any idea's or ways I can find the problem?

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var manager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var devices: [CBPeripheral] = []

    var closestRSSI = 0
    var alertCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic? = nil

    let SERVICE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "06758213-258D-44B2-A577-8AE43E9DF674")
    let ALERT_UUID = CBUUID(string: "B9FBC271-666B-4CA7-8F9C-F8E9C0223D20")
    let BATTERY_UUID = CBUUID(string: "4D757E85-6A28-48CB-9CF5-299CB72D5AB2")
    let FIRMWARE_UUID = CBUUID(string: "64CD5AF5-B6EE-4D46-A164-246BB197F5DA")
    let CLIENT_CONFIG_UUID = CBUUID(string: "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
    var characteristicUUIDArray: [CBUUID] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var connectButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        infoLabel.text = "0"
        characteristicUUIDArray = [ALERT_UUID, BATTERY_UUID, FIRMWARE_UUID]
    }

    @IBAction func connectButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state{
        case .unauthorized:
            print("Unauthorized to use BLE")
            break
        case .poweredOff:
            print("Bluetooth is currently powered off")
            break
        case .poweredOn:
            print("Bluetooth is ready to use")
            manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [SERVICE_UUID], options: nil)
            break
        case .resetting:
            print("Blueooth is resetting")
            break
        case .unknown:
            print("Bluetooth is unknown")
            break
        case .unsupported:
            print("Bluetooth is unsupported")
            break
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print(error!)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(peripheral.name ?? "Null")
        if peripheral.name != nil{
            if peripheral.name! == "Watch" {
                self.manager.stopScan()
                self.peripheral = peripheral
                self.peripheral.delegate = self
                manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        print("Disconnected")
        manager.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
        manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [SERVICE_UUID], options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("\nDid Connect To \(peripheral.name!)")
        peripheral.discoverServices([SERVICE_UUID])
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print("Did Discover Services")
        for service in peripheral.services!{
            let thisService = service

            if thisService.uuid == SERVICE_UUID{
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(characteristicUUIDArray, for: thisService)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        print("Did Discover Characteristics")
        for charateristic in service.characteristics! {
            let thisCharacter = charateristic

            if thisCharacter.uuid == ALERT_UUID{
                print("Alert")
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: thisCharacter)
            }

//            if thisCharacter.uuid == BATTERY_UUID{
//                print("Battery")
//                self.peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: thisCharacter)
//            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("Did update")
        if(characteristic.uuid == ALERT_UUID){
            print("Did Update Value For Alert")
            let content = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let value = content?.components(separatedBy: ",")
            let warning = Int(value![0])
            infoLabel.text = String(warning!)
        }

        if(characteristic.uuid == BATTERY_UUID){
            print("Did Update Value For Battery")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I am onto something. If I add a breakpoint to the didDiscovercharacteristic for alert and have it wait a moment it seems to work every time. Could there be some timing issue in setting the characteristic to notify?

Comment: So long as I have a breakpoint in the thisCharacter.uuid == ALERT_UUID it will update after I hit resume. This is a vexing problem for someone new to ios

Answer (score 0):

So I believe it was a race condition error. By Wrapping each characteristic in a delay the problem was fixed. Here is what I changed. So I believe it was a race condition error. By Wrapping each characteristic in a delay the problem was fixed. Here is what I changed. I am unsure why this fixes it but if anyone has any ideas I'd enjoy hearing why this is

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    print("Did Discover Characteristics")
    for charateristic in service.characteristics! {
        let thisCharacter = charateristic

        if thisCharacter.uuid == ALERT_UUID{
            print("Alert")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: thisCharacter)
            })
        }

        if thisCharacter.uuid == BATTERY_UUID{
            print("Battery")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: thisCharacter)
            })
        }
    }
}
```